# working on images with openCV and python

Tags: python, opencv

How to calculate absolute difference between two images using opencv and python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why didn't that work? Please include sample input and output and sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll assume that the two images are of the same size. Then, you can try this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('path/to/img1')
img2 = cv2.imread('path/to/img2')
np.abs(img1, img2)
```

Comment: Thanks.. This worked for me..